# Error: Cannot set property 'src' of null at Img field

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an image slider using JavaScript.

I took **image URLs** into an array and slides image using **javascript function**.

```js
var imageurls = ["https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/Avengers3c9095c4.jpg",
"https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/Avengers1dde2dff.jpg", 
"https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/Avengers2f856ebb.jpg.", 
"https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/Avengers40b07bc7.jpg",
"https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/Avengers51fd2ccc.jpg"];

var index=0;
document.getElementById("demo").src = imageurls[index];

function nextSlider(){
    index++;
    if(index>4){
      index=4;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").src = imageurls[index];
}

function prevSlider() {
    index--;
    if(index<0){
        index=0;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").src = imageurls[index];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Avengers Avenue</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Avengers Avenue</h1>
      <div class="img-field">
        <a class="prev" onclick="prevSlider()">&#10094;</a>
        <img id= "demo"> 
        <a class="next" onclick="nextSlider()">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I am getting this error:

[image]

**main.js:4 
Uncaught TypeError: 
Cannot set property 'src' of null
    at main.js:4**

I don't know how to resolve it? or where I am doing the mistake?

Comment: inlude your main.js  before </body>

Comment: yes. this is correct. because you are accessing element before dom load its inside body. It should be after element means `</body>` tag

Comment: have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eddited you question to a snippet and it works perfect.
So probaply have your `javascript` loaded before the `html` element is loaded.
In that case you `javascript` can't find the elment eand so it's `src`.

**Solution**

Place you `javascript` right before the end of the `<body>`, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <!-- your html...-->
    <script src="yourJS.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add javascript file right before the end of the . tag

---

---

```js
      var imageurls = [
        'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/Avengers3c9095c4.jpg',
        'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/Avengers1dde2dff.jpg',
        'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/Avengers2f856ebb.jpg.',
        'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/Avengers40b07bc7.jpg',
        'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/Avengers51fd2ccc.jpg'
      ]

      var index = 0
      document.getElementById('demo').src = imageurls[index]

      function nextSlider () {
        index++
        if (index > 4) {
          index = 4
        }
        document.getElementById('demo').src = imageurls[index]
      }

      function prevSlider () {
        index--
        if (index < 0) {
          index = 0
        }
        document.getElementById('demo').src = imageurls[index]
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Avengers Avenue</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Avengers Avenue</h1>
      <div class="img-field">
        <a class="prev" onclick="prevSlider()">&#10094;</a>
        <img id= "demo"> 
        <a class="next" onclick="nextSlider()">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script> /* include here */

    </body>
</html>
```